# Views sliding pager

Tags: 7, views

I googled so much time but i couldn't find what i'm looking for.
My views i have a image slideshow and pager for it, i set the pager as field and selected image field(thumbnails).
i select a controller too in the bottom but what i need is when click on next or previous links the pager(Thumbnails) only must go (sliding) right or left according to the direction.
Description:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this module http://drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic, it will match your requirement and use css for customization.

Hope it helps you!.

Answer (score 0):

firs : Set the number of item in the pager or make it to display all item
Second : on the setting of slide show use the controller (prev, next)
use this model is simple and useful for you [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

Comment: it's not what i need, already using views slideshow in my views. it's for sliding the pager elements not the images